# Add random class to element but no repeat again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which adds a random class to a list. How can I avoid repeating the class name again in the list?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var classes = ["col-1", "col-2", "col-3", "col-4", "col-5", "col-6"];

    $("#megamenu #nav li").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have as many unique classes as you have `li`s, you could do this.

```js
function shuffle(obj) {
  var i = obj.length;
  var rnd, tmp;

  while (i) {
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    i -= 1;
    tmp = obj[i];
    obj[i] = obj[rnd];
    obj[rnd] = tmp;
  }

  return obj;
}

var classes = ["col-1", "col-2", "col-3", "col-4", "col-5", "col-6"];

shuffle(classes);
$("#megamenu #nav li").each(function() {
  $(this).addClass(classes.pop());
});
```

```css
.col-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.col-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.col-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.col-4 {
  background-color: green;
}

.col-5 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.col-6 {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="megamenu">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

First we shuffle the `classes` using a Fisher-Yates shuffle, we then remove an entry from `classes` and assign it to a `li`, this way it can not be used again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use splice to remove the used item from the array

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var classes = ["col-1", "col-2", "col-3", "col-4", "col-5", "col-6"];

    $("#megamenu #nav li").each(function () {
        var idx = ~~ (Math.random() * classes.length);
        $(this).addClass(classes[idx]);
        classes.splice(idx, 1)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BLBBd/)

Comment: my bad, i thought something else

Answer (score 0):

Many options:

1. If you don't want to use the same class again, then delete it from the array once you use it using `splice` as already answered.
2. If you want to keep the class in the array (maybe use it again later) you can add the used classes to 2nd array (let's called it blacklist), and then check before using classes if they are already in `blacklist`.

**Option 2 implementation:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var classes = ["col-1", "col-2", "col-3", "col-4", "col-5", "col-6"];
    var blacklist = [];
    $("#megamenu #nav li").each(function () {
        var index = ~~ (Math.random() * classes.length);
         var currClass = classes[index ];
      if(! $.inArray(currClass , blacklist ))  //or you can use the array index instead of class name.    
        $(this).addClass(currClass );
         blacklist.push(currClass );        
    });
});
```

3.use classes array as an object and put **used** attribute once the class has been used.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     var classes = {
        0:{name:"col-1", used:false},
        1:{name:"col-2", used:false},
        2:{name:"col-3", used:false},
        3:{name:"col-4", used:false},
        4:{name:"col-5", used:false},
        5:{name:"col-6", used:false}
        };
    $("#megamenu #nav li").each(function () {
        var index = ~~ (Math.random() * Object.keys(classes).length);            
      if(classes[index].used === false))
        $(this).addClass(classes[index].name);            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no critical dependency in your application you can use `sort` as a primitive shuffle:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var classes = ["col-1", "col-2", "col-3", "col-4", "col-5", "col-6"];
    classes.sort(function(){ return Math.random() - .5 });

    $("#megamenu #nav li").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(classes.pop());
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hrUer/)